# student inside school query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a `schools` table and a `students` table.
The `students` table is connected to the `schools` table and has the columns `NAME` and `BIRTHDATE`.

I need all the *schools* that have *students* inside them, who are called "*jim*" or "*mike*" and are born on the same day.

Something like :

```
select *
  from schools s
  join student st in st.schoolId = s.Id
  where (...)
```

Comment: Show us db schema,  sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You can't compare different rows in the same table with a `WHERE` clause, you'll need to join students to students, or use a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: i get you..can you show me example of that solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be using tow time the tables related  inner joi  by birthdate

```
select t1.id from ( 
    select s.id , st.name, st.birthdate
    from schools s
    join student st in st.schoolId = s.Id
    where st.name  = 'jim' 
) t1 
inner join ( 
    select s.id , st.name, st.birthdate
    from schools s
    join student st in st.schoolId = s.Id
    where st.name  = 'mike' 
) t2 on t1.birthdate = t2.birthdate
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by joining students with schools twice

```
select  distinct s.*
from    schools s
join    student st1
on      st.schoolId = s.Id
join    student st2
on      st.schoolId = s.Id
where   st1.birthdate = st2.birthdate and
        st1.name = 'Jim' and
        st2.name = 'Mike'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use conditional aggregation to find the `schoolId`s that have both the names per `birthdate` and `join` (or use `IN`) with schools table to get the relevant details.

```
select s.*
from schools s
join (
    select distinct schoodId
    from student
    where name in ('jim', 'mike')
    group by schoodId,
        birthdate
    having count(distinct name) = 2
    ) st on s.Id = st.schoodId;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be looking for:

```
select s.*
from schools s
    cross apply (select birthdate, name from students st where st.schoolId = s.Id and st.name = 'Jim') studentJim
    cross apply (select birthdate, name from students st where st.schoolId = s.Id and st.name = 'Mike') studentMike
where studentJim.birthDate = studentMike.birthDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
select * from schools
where schools.id IN (

(select 
    s1.schoolID
from 
   student s1 inner join student s2
   on 
      (s1.schoolID = s2.schoolID) --seem school
      AND (s1.birthdate = s2.birthdate) --seem birthdate
      AND ((s1.name like '% jim %') OR (s1.name like '% mike %'))) --name jim or mike
)
```

hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Another form (I haven't tested it) could be:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM SCHOOLS S
 INNER JOIN (
             SELECT A.SCHOOL_ID 
             FROM STUDENT A
             INNER JOIN STUDENT B ON A.BIRTHDATE = B.BIRTHDATE  AND A.SCHOOL_ID= B.SCHOOL_ID
             WHERE A.NAME = 'JIM'
             AND B.NAME = 'MIKE'
            ) C ON S.ID = C.SCHOOL_ID
```